# OAuth2 with Spring Boot -> "status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials"

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a little problem that I can not get any further.
I try to program a REST API with Spring Boot.

I used the following example:
[Spring Boot REST API (4) - Security with OAuth2](https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2017/03/01/spring-boot-4.html)

The example works well too, I get back a token after the transmission.
Unfortunately, it does not work in my own project and I just do not know why. When I try to issue the following command from the command line, I get the following error message back.

> curl -X POST --user 'testuser:secret' -d 'grant_type=password&username=Sample&password=password' http://localhost:8080/Api/oauth/token

Answer:

> {"timestamp":1514905794221,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/Api/oauth/token"}

in the logfile i found the following:

> 2018-01-02 16:09:53.956 DEBUG 25056 --- [qtp561480862-19] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User 'testuser' not found

but this user has nothing to do with the normal users. he is in the OAuth2conf.java

this is the content of this file:

```
    package com.builtt.webservice.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;

import com.company.webservice.BuilttApiApplication;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter 
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuth2Config.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Value("${api.oauth.tokenTimeout:3600}")
    private int expiration;

    // password encryptor
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
    {
        logger.info("Create Password Encoder ... .. .");
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception 
    {
        logger.info("Set OAuth Config ... .. .");
        configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception 
    {
        logger.info("Config Client ... .. .");
        clients.inMemory().withClient("testuser").secret("secret").accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
                .scopes("read", "write").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .resourceIds("resource");
    }

}
```

can one of you estimate where to look for the problem?

her is the POM File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.webservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>API</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>API</name>
    <description>Sample API TEST</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         </dependency>
        <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Check your "UserDetailsService " and  "UserRepository " implementations..

Comment: Have the same problem